# Can infrared cameras be used in the presence of light or is it compulsory it has to be used in the dark, to get a thermal image of the desired object?

Tags: infrared, camera, thermal, imageprocessing

The question I asked could seem silly but I was wondering if there was a way of capturing the heat signatures of objects or people even during the day time. Also if we were to use an infrared camera, should we maintain the camera at a much lower temperature in order for it to capture the thermal information; i.e a cooling system?

Comment: You need to review [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6869/1638) on the Physics StackExchange.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about EE

Comment: Thermographic cameras work fine in the light. They're commonly used in generating stations and substations for checking for damaged or loose conductors (they heat up and are easily visible on the thermograph). As for the second question, both cooled and uncooled cameras are available. Uncooled are cheaper and much more common. Cooled cameras are mainly for speciality applications where extra sensitivity is required. In most cases, you'll be buying a thermographic camera from FLIR, who are pretty much the Big Name in thermography.

Answer (score 2):

Infrared light and visible light has nothing to do with each other (well, not much). An infrared camera works the same in a bright room as it does in the dark. It captures the same thermal image. There should be little, if any, difference. At least indoors.

However, the sun also generates infrared light. And the sun also heats up things. You can still capture thermal images outside but what you're capturing is just that - an image of how hot objects are. If you're in the desert for example, almost everything will be roughly the same temperature (except maybe a large block of ice melting slowly). If you're in snow then mammals and car engines will look hot.

What you need is not a cooling system for the camera. What you need is a cooling system for "outside" from the sun. Conveniently we get that naturally when night comes. So it's not the darkness of night that makes thermal cameras more effective at night. It's the lack of heat form the sun.

Comment: I did know that the surrounding temperature should be comparitively low in order to get great heat signatures. But i thought light was also a contributing factor. I wanted to find out a way to by-pass the problem of maintaining the surrounding temperature low, thereby enabling themto use even during the day when the ambient temperature is quite high